Smarty plugin alias name to point different names to same function.plugin.php file
Is there a way to create one Smarty plugin and name it , for example "coreplugin" and put it in the file function.coreplugin.php but in a template i would like to call it will different names.
Example,
{coreplugin arg1="val1" arg2="val2" ...}

and also
{customname arg1="val1" arg2="val2" ...}

I would like to register somewhere customname is an alias to coreplugin . And then in the function.coreplugin.php i would like to get a name used to call it.
Is there a way to make it easy ?
